# Incorrect RDD tranformation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am unable to re-use the new RDD that has formed by doing mapPartition. The code seems to work fine only if I add `reduceByKey` transformation after the mapPartition (I do not want to perform `reduceByKey`). Since `reduceByKey` and `mapParition` are both transformations I am not sure what is causing error.

```
C = [x for x in xrange(2**20)]
C = sc.parallelize(C)
while True:
    C = C.repartition(1000)\
        .mapPartitions(foo)\
        .persist()

    if C.take(1) == 0 :
        break
```

Error reported:

```
TypeError: can't pickle listiterator objects
```

Comment: try range instead of xrange. Xrange produces generator `C = [x for x in range(2**20)]`, also repartitioning with while true loop is very bad coding.

Comment: @Pushkr xrange is preferred over range in such kind of applications

Comment: yes but only in python2, with python3 range is same as xrange. And for parallelizing , you need actual list and not generator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to what you are returning from the mapPartitions is what I believe. If you return a new RDD, I do not see a reason for the code to raise an exception. Following is the code snippet which I developed by using your code.

```
def f(it):
    s = 0
    l = 0

    for x in it:
        s += x
        l += 1
        if l > 1:
             yield s

C = sc.parallelize([x for x in range(100)])

while True:
      C = C.repartition(10)\
          .mapPartitions(f)
      if C.isEmpty():
          break
```

It's preferred to use `isEmpty()` over `take(1)` to check the whether RDD is empty or not.